# Foursquare API venue tips endpoint doesn't collect all tips

Tags: foursquare

I want to collect all tips from certain venue in foursquare API.
I tried https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/tips venue endpoints, but why it didn't collect all tips?
For example, if i enter '51f34889498e9ce99e5a16fa' as venue id input, it shows that there's 142 tips for that venue, but when i count the tips list, there's only 36 tips that have been successfully collected. If i add parameter limit=500 and offset=100, there's 55 tips that have been collected. Still less than it should.
Anyone have explanation about this phenomenon?